# Styling OptionMenu on android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-support-library

[image: original option menu]

Here is the default Option Menu style in android. Currently I tried.

My question is : I want to override the default to style of Option Menu. Like this!
[image]

which is only `first character is cap` and `custom typeface`.

Here is my implememtation.

```
//style.xml
 <style name="HomeTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/apercu</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>
   <style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Menu</item>
    </style>
   <style name="TextAppearance.Menu" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/custom_type_face</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#4d4d4d</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: What is question? you have already implemented? any errors?

Comment: things didn't change It show as first photo . Althought  i override in `style.xml` mention above

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished it overriding `AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton`. Eg.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

and set it to my `Activity`'s theme like

```
<item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.ActionButton</item>
```